# Boot loader keeps adding eax to al

Tags: assembly, gdb, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm trying to build my first bootloader, and it actually works, but thers is one thing that happens, according to gdb, that I don't understand.

This is my bootloader written in nasm:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16
start: jmp boot

msg db "Bootinggggg!", 0

Print:
lodsb ;loading si to al
cmp al,0 ;loop
je PrintDone
mov ah,0eh
mov bl,14 ;yellow color
int 10h
jmp Print 

PrintDone:
ret

boot:
mov ah,00h
mov al,0eh
int 10h ;stepping into graphic mode
mov si,msg
call Print
cli
cld
hlt


times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

I use qemu and visualize 8086 architecture, on my unbuntu machine. After using `ni` command few times in gdb, the gdb shows that the program just adds eax to al, endlessly. I pressed `ni` many times, and it just keeps adding it. But when I press continue it actually works, as you can see it prints the string. Why is it happening?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is going on here is that likely when you hit the `int 10h` instruction GDB (not QEMU) got confused. GDB has no notion of realmode segment and offset addressing. When it disassembles instructions it uses the EIP register to determine where in memory to show instructions.It ignored the fact that that when `Int 10h` occurred that CS became a non-zero value and started to show instructions in memory that QEMU isn't actually executing. GDB debugging by default doesn't do a very good job of debugging real mode code.

Comment: If you want to debug a bootloader with the fewest hassles use BOCHs. It understands realmode segment:offset addressing and does a very good job with code like this.

Comment: Effectively those add %al, (%eax) (the result of disassembling memory with all zeroes) are the instructions GDB thinks QEMU is executing, while QEMU is actually executing the proper code. After `int 10h` finishes and reaches its IRET control will be returned back to your bootloader where GDB should start displaying the proper instructions again.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're disassembling blank memory. `00 00` is the encoding of `add %al, (%eax)` or `add [eax], al`. You can check that easily with [this online disassembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly)

```
0:  00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
```

Note that the instruction is not *adding eax to al*. It adds al to the value at the address pointed to by eax

Comment: So why does it play the yellow string only after I type 'continue', and not after the corresponding assembly commend?

Comment: Presumably control got out of the `hlt` somehow, e.g. due to the debugger using `int3`. To make an endless loop, it's best to put a `jmp` back to the `hlt`.

Comment: @jester Would'nt it be better to avoid an endless loop? where should I place the  'jmp'?

Comment: `l: hlt; jmp l`

Comment: In this case GDB is showing instructions that QEMU isn't actually executing. Because GDB has no notion of segment:offset addressing in real mode - when `int 10h` is done CS and IP were modified to start executing in BIOS memory (likely above physical address 0xF0000). GDB just used the IP(EIP) value to disassemble instructions and ignored the value in CS. Of course in real mode CS:IP together point to a physical address with the formula (segment<<4)+offset GDB doesn't understand that.